# How peek() works?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

// All 3 queries (1:push, 2:delete, 3:print max) are all O(1) runtime
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> stack    = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> maxStack = new Stack<Integer>(); // keeps track of maximums

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int query = scan.nextInt();
            switch (query) {
                case 1:
                    int x = scan.nextInt();
                    stack.push(x);
                    if (maxStack.isEmpty() || x >= maxStack.peek()) {
                        maxStack.push(x);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    int poppedValue = stack.pop();
                    if (poppedValue == maxStack.peek()) {
                        maxStack.pop();
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println(maxStack.peek());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
}
        }        
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

This is  code for finding max value in the stack i want to know that if `peek()` chooses the top element of the stack than how it will peek if there is an element greater than top value like in between the stack. how it will determine the max value

Comment: `peek()` doesn't have the magical property you are ascribing to it, but your code does, assuming it works correctly.

Comment: Yeah correct  simple logic...got it

Answer (score 0):

With you case (max in between) it works fine:
If you have values in the `stack`: `1,4,5,3,2,1` - then `maxStack` will contain 5 as the top element. And executing `case 2:` will leave `stack` with `1,2,5,3,2` and `maxStack` will not be popped so still have 5 as top element.

However with the sequence of `1,2,3,5,5` delete query will execute pop() from both `stack` and `maxStack` which leads to:

`stack` -> 1,2,3,5

`maxStack` -> 1,2,3

Which I believe is a flaw in the logic.